# Sensible line buffer size in C?

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, fgets

I'm using popen to read output from shell commands. I will use fgets to read line by line.
My question is how to choose the best buffer size for my char* buffer? I remember from a professor telling us to include `<limits.h>` and use `LINE_MAX` for such things. It works fine on my Mac, but there's no `LINE_MAX` on Linux.

This mailing list archive poses the same question, but no answer to my question
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/843278-not-able-locate-line_max-limits-h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When [`<limits.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) does not define `LINE_MAX`, look at `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX`, which is required to be at least 2048.  I usually use 4096.

Also look for the (new) POSIX functions [`getline()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and `getdelim()` - both at the same URL.  These allocate memory as necessary.

---

#### Program (`posix2_line_max.c`)

```
#include "posixver.h"
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", _POSIX2_LINE_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2048
```

#### `posixver.h`

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2001 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600   /* SUS v3, POSIX 1003.1 2004 (POSIX 2001 + Corrigenda) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

Tested on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative; command line:

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror  posix2_line_max.c -o posix2_line_max
```

Comment: It defines neither. I tried defining the macros `__USE_POSIX2`, `__USE_POSIX`, `__USE_XOPEN` before including the header `limits.h` but to no avail :( I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @ajay: the macros you tried setting are completely controlled by the compilation system for its own purposes; they are completely reset at the start of a compilation and then set by the system based on the flags that you set to control the compilation.  You need to set `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` for most purposes — see the code added to the answer.  Or `_GNU_SOURCE` or …

Comment: Thank you so much :) You are a one-stop solution to all problems and doubts in `C` on SO. :) Just one more last question. Is using a buffer larger than `LINE_MAX` OK? Like you said you usually use 4096.

Comment: Yes; it is just a lower bound. You make a judgement call. If you think you might be dealing with data without newlines (JSON? HTML? Javascript?) then you have to worry about the limits. If you're not dealing with data without newlines, you can afford to go smaller.  It's a complex decision. You need to worry about checking whether you got a newline (or use `getline()`). In part, I use 4096 for shock value, to jolt people out of the 80 byte or 256 byte mindset. Machines with gigabytes of main memory aren't hurt by 4k buffers (within fairly broad limits).

Answer (score 5):

`man getline`

Also see http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html and the discussion of `getline()` vs. `fgets()` vs. `gets()`.  Has been subject on SO more often than I can count as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `malloc()` and expand if necessary, or use the source and look at how a GNU utility does it.

Comment: okay I'll check out a GNU utility. I'm using malloc, but only once, and reusing the same line buffer.

Comment: I always look for code in GNU or good open source projects. Or you could grow the heap space dynamically (to a point) but this can be slow (to copy everything back).

Answer (score 0):

check the line for an '\n', if not exists expand the buffer before you call the next fgets.

Comment: You also need to check `feof()` if there's no `'\n'`, to account for the corner-case of the last line in the file not having a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX systems have [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) which will allocate a buffer for you.

On non-POSIX systems, you can use Chuck B. Falconer's public domain `ggets` function, which is similar. (Chuck Falconer's website is no longer available, although [archive.org has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20080525133110/http://cbfalconer.home.att.net/download/), and I've made [my own page for `ggets`](http://www.taenarum.com/software/ggets/).)

Comment: It's also pretty easy to implement a portable and fast `getline`, with full support for embedded null characters just like the original GNU version, using only `realloc`, `fgets`, `memset`, and `memchr`. This is probably a lot better than `ggets`, which seems to have broken behavior for newlines/end of file and no way of handling embedded nulls, but it really depends on your application and what you need.

Comment: @R..: AFAIK there aren't any EOF issues with `ggets` anymore, and while it's true it doesn't handle embedded NULs, I don't think that's a common use case. (It's also not something that's directly supported by `fgets`, and I'm not sure how you would build something around `fgets` that distinguishes embedded NUL bytes from the actual end.  It certainly doesn't seem as trivial as you make it out to be.)

Comment: How in the world do you distinguish between a final line ending with a newline and a final line missing a newline, using `ggets`? If you can't, then it's a lossy function. The loss may not matter for many uses, but I still consider it a major limitation. As for `fgets` and embedded nulls, it's easy. You memset your buffer with `'\n'` before calling `fgets` and then searching for `'\n'` with `memchr` tells how many bytes were read.

Comment: Good point about the lossiness of `ggets`.  OTOH, I've personally seen way more cases where `fgets` consumers strip off the trailing newline incorrectly than I've seen cases where they care about preserving a missing `'\n'`.  As for detecting embedded NULs, clever, but a pathological implementation could fill the entire buffer on every non-empty read.

Comment: No, the standard specifies what `fgets` does, which is formally equivalent to making repeated calls to `fgetc` and storing the results in the buffer until it's full or `\n` is encountered. Writing past that point is not following the specification.

Comment: @R..: Can you point me to where it says so, because 7.19.7.2 in the C99 standard doesn't mention anything like that.

Comment: I was going by the documentation in POSIX which is aligned with ISO C99. Specifying everything in terms of `fgetc` and `fputc` may be a POSIXism, but the citation you provided clearly specifies what is written into the array ("at most one less than the number of characters specified by n" followed by a terminating null character). Standard library functions can't just randomly clobber memory outside of what they're specified to do.

Comment: @R..: That clearly specifies what's *read*, not what's *written*.  I don't interpret the language of 7.19.7.2 as prohibiting an `fgets` implementation from clearing the rest of the buffer after the terminating NUL.

Comment: Um, the specification clearly is about what's written to memory; otherwise a conformant implementation could just read and discard all the characters. Unless the specification says that the contents of the rest of the buffer are unspecified after the call to `fgets`, then `fgets` **cannot** clobber it.

Comment: @R..: The specification states that the characters are *read into the buffer*, so it can't discard them.  The limitation of "at most n - 1" characters is what's read from the stream; it's not a limitation on writes beyond that.  Moreover, even if it were, always filling the remaining portion of the buffer always would be within the "at most n - 1" bound.  I don't see why the specification wouldn't give vendors some latitude here.  For example, a system might want to write, say, 4 bytes at a time without having to read back the old contents.

Comment: It might want to, but it would be incorrect and non-conformant. An implementation can't just go clobbering memory outside of what it's specified to do. As an extreme case take this thought experiment: a conforming application could, when reading a file the application itself generated, pass a value larger size value than the actual buffer size to `fgets`, knowing the maximum length of any actual line in the file. This would not be a good idea on multitasking/multiuser systems where another process could modify the file, but in isolation, it's perfectly valid.